# Equivalent of [CBUUID UUIDWithString: @"9abd"] in swift

Tags: objective-c, swift

What is the Swift equivalent of this objective-C code snippet:

```
[CBUUID UUIDWithString: @"9abd"]
```

I tried:

```
let uuid = UUID(uuidString: "9abd") // this is nil
let cbuuid = CBUUID(nsuuid: uuid!)
```

But the `UUID` is nil.

Thanks!

Comment: I have no idea how you got your attempt. The correct answer seems very straightforward: `CBUUID(string: "9abd")`.

Answer (score 1):

Because of creating an UUID need a valid string like `7AFD7082-7A14-44F8-B839-5C4D98842798`
According to Apple's document:

> **Parameters**
>
> > The source string containing the UUID. The standard format for UUIDs represented in ASCII is a string punctuated by hyphens, for example 68753A44-4D6F-1226-9C60-0050E4C00067.

> **Return Value**
>
> > A new UUID object. Returns nil for invalid strings.